# WPF binding to nullable object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Assuming I have a list of employee

And my employee class

Class employees{
String name
Address? address
}

I have a data grid that show all my employees and it address

Name. Address.
Sam.   Null
Peter. USA

I need to create a address object to Sam and bound to it automatically when I edit the cell value of Sam address.

I tried converter but nothing came

Comment: Please include the converter code and xaml binding

Comment: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0). What exactly is your question? *"nothing came"* is not a question. All we know is you *"tried converter but nothing came"*. Meaningless information for somebody that doesn't know anything about your code, your goals and expectations. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Solution in .NET7:

First, I created Employee simple calss

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _address;
    private string _name;

    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }

    public string? Address
    {
        get => _address;
        set => _address = value;
    }
}
```

In backend code I initialized list, added some employees and notified GUI about it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
        {
            new Employee() { Name = "Sam" },
            new Employee() { Name = "Peter", Address = "USA" }
        };

        RaiseProperChanged(nameof(Employees));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

In view part i did this:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Now when I am edditing address column for Sam, and then lose focus from cell, it hit my setter from Employee class. Now in that setter you can do whatever you want with new address.

Comment: Don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on DependencyObject types like Window. Instead implement properties as dependency properties.

Comment: Because you bind to the Employee (Employee is a binding source) Employee must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Firing a property change notification for the Employees property is pointless anyway. It is only set in the constructor and should therefore be a readonly property. In general, you never need to fire change notifications from constructors.